# How can I load tailwind classes that are sent via actioncable broadcast in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css, hotwire-rails, turbo

I'm running a rails app that is heavily using hotwire in some pages. All the CSS in the app is "written" using tailwindcss classes.

In some pages there are a lot of turbo broadcasts being sent by the server based on user interaction. One of the partials that is being sent is this

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-<%= question.answers.count %> gap-5">
  ...
</div
```

Assuming that the question has four answers, the class used in that div is `grid-cols-4`, however, since this class isn't used on page load tailwind doesn't bundle it up with the css file sent over to the client. This means that when the broadcast is eventually loaded on the client side that class does not apply the style I would expect.

I confirmed that this is the case by adding a dummy `div` element rendered on page load that is using this `grid-cols-4` class and indeed the broadcasted partial is rendered the way I would expect it to render.

How can I make sure tailwind bundles up also the style that may be used in my broadcasted partials?

To add some context - this is what the broadcast looks like

```
broadcast_update_to "#{broadcast_id(school_class)}_teacher", target: "spark-container",
   partial: "sparks/teacher/question_with_answers",
   locals: {
     spark: self,
     question: question,
     school_class: school_class
   }
```

This is what my `postcss.config.js` looks like

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('tailwindcss')('./app/javascript/stylesheets/tailwind.config.js'),
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
    require('postcss-preset-env')({
      autoprefixer: {
        flexbox: 'no-2009'
      },
      stage: 3
    })
  ]
}
```

And this is what my tailwind config looks like

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  purge: {
    enabled: ["production", "staging"].includes(process.env.NODE_ENV),
    content: [
      './app/**/*.html.erb',
      './app/helpers/**/*.rb',
      './app/javascript/**/*.js',
    ],
  },
  theme: {
    extend: {}
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
    require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
    require('@tailwindcss/line-clamp'),
    require('@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio'),
  ],
}
```

Comment: You may add safelist [configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71422057/tailwind-fully-compile-css-without-stripping-unused-classes/71466431#71466431)